# TableView action doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created an UITableViewRowAction with these code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: {(action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        })

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

        var error: NSError?

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Task")

        let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]

        managedContext.deleteObject(fetchedResults[indexPath.row])
        table.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

    }
```

When I run it, the rows can be swiped to the left, but no button was shown.

I added this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: {(action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

    })

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

And deleted the code in commitEditingStyle, and it still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I enabled size classes, when I run it on iPhone6 simulator, swiping it to the left won't show the button. But when I change the simulator to resizable iPhone, it's shown on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `UITableviewRowAction`,You delegate method is not right

Try this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let action = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "First") { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        //Do action here
    }
    action.backgroundColor = UIColor .greenColor()
      return [action]
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it still has the problem. What do you mean by delegate method is not right?

Comment: I mean the delegate method for `UITableviewRowAction` is `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath `.